# Could anybody learn the secrets of celestial weapons?

Tags: weapon, kshatriya

I think there is some condemnation of Drona the Brahmin for encroaching on the realm of warriors. Is there a prohibition on non-Kshatriyas learning those weapons?

Comment: there is no condemnation on Drona learning. in fact, only brahmanas are supposed to teach it. the issue was with Dronacharya using the weapons and actually fighting in war, which is the duty of kshatriyas.

Comment: Is your question about Drona the Brahmin learning the warfare or all the non Kshatriyas?